# What is the best way to lock a file through NFS

Tags: locking, posix, sh, nfs

I'm looking for a way to lock a file through NFS on a Unix operating system. The state of the art does not seem very enjoyable. I tried flock, which does not work properly.

What is the best and most POSIX (or at least Unix) option now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lockfile` seems to be the best (or less bad) solution. cf `man lockfile` :

```
MISCELLANEOUS
   Lockfile is NFS-resistant and eight-bit clean.
```

Answer (score 0):

use fcntl which is a better locking mechanism and supports byte range locking as well.

Comment: Thanks for the trick, but I need something I can use with sh.